# QString bad display

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I'm quite new to Qt and I've a problem that I've never seen before : when I update the text of a QLabel the QString change of value juste before the assignation.

Here's my code :

dom.cpp

```
if (noeud.nodeName().toStdString() == "roles"){
            cout << endl << "Value of nbroles: "<< nbroles;
            w.addmsg("" + nbroles);
        }
```

info.cpp

```
void info::addmsg(QString str){
    this->txt->setText(this->txt->text() +"\n"+ str);
    this->txt->adjustSize();
    cout << endl << "add : " << str.toStdString();
}
```

And here's my output :

```
Value of nbroles : 41
add : 'm not here
```

> 'm not here

is a part of a string which is a few lines under in a function that's never called.

I don't understand and it's blowing my mind...
Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's going on, I think. You are passing `"" + nbroles` to function that expects `QString`. So `QString::QString(const char*)` constructor is called. The argument of that constructor is `"" + nbroles`, which is not concatenation of empty string and `nbroles` converted to string, but some pointer to arbitrary memory - address of string literal `""` incremented by `nbroles` bytes.

Try calling your function this way:

```
w.addmsg(QString::number(nbroles));
```